# guardar json en base de datos

Tags: php, json

Quiero guardar un json en una tabla de la base de datos, pero no esta guardando los datos y tampoco sale errores cuando recargo la pagina.

puse estos datos de custom para probar, pero la idea es guardar los datos que vienen desde un api, pero no se porque no funciona.

```
$json = '[{
    "document": "asudhau",
    "firstName": "uhsaudhau",
    "lastName": "$2y$10$KAg3wt7bBjphgdCNJf4VXe.an8lOnlOvWVdVsh2Qsws0dbhWiDwkO",
    "gender": "usaudha@hotmail.com",
    "email": "F",
    "phone": 34,
    "productPurchasedTag": "2016-10-06"
},
{
    "document": "abudasd",
    "firstName": "hasdua",
    "lastName": "$2y$10$c781KdL3ERgDCnP6MR28xuf\/dnKjuVajklc0uSj2FnBrZSB1H88Si",
    "gender": "uhasiuda@hotmail.com",
    "email": "F",
    "phone": 35,
    "productPurchasedTag": "1990-02-03"
},
{
    "document": "audihaiudh",
    "firstName": "uiahsdiuahdi",
    "lastName": "$2y$10$Q7VjafKxt\/kuJS1BrslF0uSZPwHe7Hvp6olMxetgY31KcmMT9dIo2",
    "gender": "hiuahdiuah@hotmail.com",
    "email": "F",
    "phone": 36,
    "productPurchasedTag": "1999-02-03"
}
]';
```

los campos de la tabla los cree con el mismo nombre de los objetos y agregue un campo extra "id" para el auto incremento.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "bd_usuarios";

//conexión db
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la conexion de la base de datos");

$datos = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($datos as $row) {

    mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO usuarios (document, firstName, lastName, gender, email, phone, productPurchasedTag) 
    VALUES ('".$row['document']."',".$row['firstName'].",'".$row['lastName']."','".$row['gender']."','".$row['email']."',".$row['phone']."',".$row['productPurchasedTag'].")");
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Gracias.

Comment: Revisa los entrecomillados, o mejor aún, usa *sentencias preparadas*.

Answer (score 2):

Tu código sería menos confuso si hicieras lo siguiente:

1. En la conversión del JSON evitas forzar una conversión a array. Esto se hace dejando de pasar `true` como segundo parámetro de `json_encode`. Al hacer eso sigues trabajando en un contexto de JSON, que permite una sintaxis más clara y más elegante. Es mucho más claro escribir esto: `$row->propiedad` que escribir esto: `$row['propiedad']`. En el primer caso no se usan comillas, y eso aporta muchísimo en cadenas como la sentencia `INSERT` que vas a construir, que lleva por otros lados comillas simples para rodear aquellos valores que son cadenas.
2. Escribes toda la sentencia dentro de un bloque rodeado por comillas dobles en la apertura y en el cierre. Haciendo eso, puedes escribir **toda la sentencia** dentro de un mismo bloque, sin tener que usar concatenaciones con el punto (`.`). También, como te sugiere @DiegoMesa, conviene que escribas código identado, que sea fácil de analizar y de leer.

El código quedaría entonces así:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "bd_usuarios";

//conexión db
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la conexion de la base de datos");

#CAMBIO AQUÍ: omitimos el parámetro true, para que no fuerce $datos a array como dijimos en (1)
$datos = json_decode($json);

foreach ($datos as $row) {
    #CAMBIO AQUÍ: usamos una variable $sql para más claridad y aplicamos lo dicho en (2)
    $sql="INSERT INTO usuarios 
            (
                document, 
                firstName, 
                lastName, 
                gender, 
                email, 
                phone, 
                productPurchasedTag
            ) 
            VALUES 
            (
                '$row->document',
                '$row->firstName',
                '$row->lastName',
                '$row->gender',
                '$row->email',
                 $row->phone,
                '$row->productPurchasedTag'
            )";
    mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

El código es fácilmente analizable escrito de ese modo. Observa la elegancia que tiene la variable `$sql`, gana muchísimo en claridad al usar la notación `$row->propiedad` en cada caso. Aquí, siguiendo el tipo de dato que viene en el JSON, he asumido que `phone` es de tipo numérico en la base de datos, por eso no he usado comillas simples para encerrar ese dato. Si en la base de datos fuera del tipo `VARCHAR` entonces tendrías que encerrarlo entre comillas simples, como están los otros datos.

## Otras observaciones

1. Como te sugería ayer en otra pregunta sobre este código, considera aplicar consultas preparadas para dar seguridad y más eficacia a tu programa. Un usuario mal intencionado podría manipular los datos e inyectar código malicioso en el programa. Aparte de eso, las consultas preparadas son más rápidas en sentencias que deben repetirse, como es el caso de estas, que están en un bucle.
2. Si no recuerdo mal, se trataba de insertar varias filas. En esos casos conviene usar transacciones.
3. En el código de ayer usabas el estilo orientado a objetos de `mysqli`. Aquí veo que has pasado al estilo procedural. Te recomendaría que mantengas el estilo orientado a objetos. Es más claro, más moderno y menos *verboso* que el estilo procedural.

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en la falta de comilla inicial para telefono `'".$row['email']."',".$row['phone']."',"`

recomendable que realices salto de linea para visualizar mejor el codigo, lo hace de mas lineas pero puedes indetificar mejor los errores de sintaxis.

```php
 mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios ( 
    document, 
    firstName, 
    lastName, 
    gender, 
    email, 
    phone, 
    productPurchasedTag ) 
  VALUES 
   ('".$row['document']."',"
   ."'".$row['firstName']."',"
   ."'".$row['lastName']."',"
   ."'".$row['gender']."',"
   ."'".$row['email']."',"
   ."'".$row['phone']."',"
   ."'".$row['productPurchasedTag'].")"
);
```